# Using sql.each with async callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, asynchronous, callback

I am using the [sqlite module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite) from npm ([not sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3)).

I need to use an async function on each row of the database. However any async code is causing an error.

The following snippet

```
async function scanDatabase() {
  console.log("Scanning database...");
  sql
    .each(`SELECT * FROM users`, async function(err, row) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      console.log(row);
      let member = await guild.fetchMember(row.id);
      console.log(member);
      console.log(row.id);
      console.log(member.user.username);

    })
    .then(function() {
      console.log("finished scanning the database");
    });
}
```

Yields the following:

```
Scanning database...
{ id: 119351283999047680,
  first_payment: '2018-03-09T11:26:26.989Z',
  last_payment: '2018-03-09T12:56:19.784Z',
  expires: '2018-03-16T10:26:26.987Z' }
(node:12292) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
(rejection id: 2): Error: Invalid or uncached id provided.
(node:12292) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are 
deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will 
terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
finished scanning the database
```

I get the unhandled promise errors, but I don't know how to fix " Error: Invalid or uncached id provided."

Comment: sqlite just sits on top of sqlite3, the signature of each is `// Database#each(sql, [bind1, bind2, ...], [callback], [complete])`  I've a feeling the complete is when it's finished scanning all rows, and the callback is for each row.  But looking at sqlite source, that's not what it looks like how it's implemented.  Saying this I would think this might be and ideal place to use generators rather than a promise.